# count 0's in a zoo (or dataframe) object

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the # of 0's in each column in my zoo [...dataframe?], similar to how I count the # of na's.

```
dropColumns = sapply(test1_z, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

I've tried

```
View(sapply(test1_z, function(x) count(x[x==0])))
```

but count doesn't like zoo objects (test1_z).  Length works here, but not count.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

My professor recommended

```
sum(frd$col0 == 0)
```

but that only works for a single column.  I was hoping to do this over an entire dataframe.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: easier yes to troubleshoot, not necessarily easy to implement for a simple question.  Hopefully I don't have to export a bunch of data to get a simple answer

Comment: `zoo` objects and `data.frames` are very different things. This is why a reproducible example would make it clear what exactly you are working with so possible solutions can be verified to work in your specific case.

Comment: I'm sure it would, but let's see what's faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a test zoo object `z` and then use the indicated expression. If you know there are no NAs then the `na.rm = TRUE` argument can be omitted.  This also works for a data frame and also for a matrix.

```
library(zoo)

# test data
z <- zoo(BOD)
z[2:3, 1] <- 0
z[4, 2] <- 0
z[5, 1] <- NA

colSums(z == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  Time demand 
     2      1
```

Comment: hrmm, unfortunately for me my hopes for a quick answer are going to evade me.  That produces table/tabular result for sure, but every value is na (except for date due to my zoo array having na's?  not sure).

Comment: doing a apply(your.matrix, 2, function(c)sum(c!=0)) results in na's as well except for date, where there is 123... I suspect the function get's confused with 0's and na's in the mix

Comment: have added na.rm=TRUE

Comment: omg, you are my hero!

Comment: thank you for seeing the problem and trying to help without layering the issue with bureaucratic red tape

Comment: Nevertheless the rules are there for a reason. Questions which do not include minimal reproducible examples tend to be ambiguous and generate a lot of needless distracting discussion about what the question is and the different answers tend to differ more on their interpretation of the problem rather than focusing on the answer.

Comment: having the data ready is a plus, but in my case it would be more work than it's worth as my data sets are quite large, I'd have to construct a dummy data set for what I was hoping was a simple answer, and in this case it was NA=TRUE.  there is a trade off.  I think you and I found the nice balance and I appreciate you attempting the effort before red taping me

Comment: Questions are supposed to provide a minimal example, not the original data.  By not including an example extra time was taken due to the NA issue and that could have been avoided.  Also there was a question about whether you really wanted zoo objects, matrix objects and data.frame objects.